# Pass By Value/Pointer/Reference Clarification

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, pass-by-pointer

I need a once-and-for-all clarification on passing by value/pointer/reference.

If I have a variable such as

```
int SomeInt = 10;
```

And I want to pass it to a function like

```
void DoSomething(int Integer)
{
    Integer = 1;
}
```

In my current scenario when passing SomeInt to DoSomething() I want SomeInt's value to be updated based on whatever we do to it inside of DoSomething() as well as be most efficient on memory and performance so I'm not copying the variable around?. That being said which of the following prototypes would accomplish this task?

```
void DoSomething(int* Integer);
void DoSomething(int& Integer);
```

How would I actually pass the variable into the function? What is the difference between the previous two prototypes?

Finally if using a function within a class

```
class SomeClass
{
    int MyInteger;

public:
    void ChangeValue(int& NewValue)
    {
        MyInteger = NewValue;
    }
};
```

If I pass an integer into ChangeValue, when the integer I passed in get's deleted will that mean when I try to use MyInteger from within the class it will no longer be useable?

Thank you all for your time, I know this is kind of a basic question but the explanations I keep running into confuse me further.

Comment: Yes, those functions might accomplish the task.

Comment: -1 I'd be interested in a once-in-lifetime clarification how folks intend to learn a programming language as complex as C++ without looking at basic study material.

Comment: You might be interested in reading the FAQ question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functionally, all three of these work:

- pass an `int` and *change the return type* to `int` so you can return the new value, usage: `x = f(x);`

  - when you plan to set the value ***without needing to read the initial value***, it's much better to use a function like `int DoSomething();` so the caller can just say `int x = f();` without having to create `x` on an earlier line and wondering/worrying whether it needs to be initialised to anything before the call.
- pass an `int&` and set it inside the function, usage: `int x; x = ? /* if an input */; f(x);`
- pass an `int*` and set the pointed-to `int` inside the function, usage: `int x; x = ?; f(&x);`

> most efficient on memory and performance so I'm not copying the variable around

Given the C++ Standard doesn't dictate how references should be implemented by the compiler, it's a bit dubious trying to reason about their characteristics - if you care compile your code to assembly or machine code and see how it works out on your particular compiler (for specific compiler commandline options etc.).  If you need a rule of thumb, assume that references have identical performance characteristics to pointers unless profiling or generated-code inspection suggests otherwise.

For an `int` you can expect the first version above to be no slower than the pointer version, ***and possibly be faster***, because the `int` parameter can be passed and returned in a register without ever needing a memory address.

If/when/where the by-pointer version is *inlined* there's more chance that the potentially slow "needing a memory address so we can pass a pointer" / "having to dereference a pointer to access/update the value" aspect of the pass-by-pointer version can be optimised out (if you've asked the compiler to try), leaving both versions with identical performance....

Still, if you need to ask a question like this I can't imagine you're writing code where these are the important optimisation choices, so a better aim is to do what gives you the cleanest, most intuitive and robust usage for the client code... now - whether that's `x = f(x);` (where you might forget the leading `x =`), or `f(x)` where you might not realise `x` could be modified, or `f(&x)` (where some caller might think they can pass `nullptr` is a reasonable question in its own right, but separate from your performance concerns.  FWIW, the C++ FAQ Lite recommends references over pointers for this kind of situation, but I personally reject its reasoning and conclusions - it all boils down to familiarity with either convention, and how often you need to pass `const` pointer values, or pointer values where `nullptr` is a valid sentinel, that could be confused with the you-may-modify-me implication hoped for in your scenario... that depends a lot on your coding style, libraries you use, problem domain etc..

Comment: Thank you. I've been passing by pointer everywhere in my application however I've recently run into a slight performance drop and want to be 100% clear on pointers/references and how to avoid copying the variable during a function call at all costs.

Comment: You're welcome.  Passing by pointer or reference can be useful when you're passing large objects that are slow to copy, but given `int` is no larger and may be smaller than a pointer, it's not helpful for `int`.  Do try a profiler (e.g. g++/VC++ have inbuilt ones, ValGrind etc) - that may turn up all sorts of unexpected things that will make a more dramatic difference.

Answer (score 4):

Both of your examples

```
void DoSomething(int* Integer);
void DoSomething(int& Integer);
```

will accomplish the task. In the first case - with pointer - you need to call the function with `DoSomething(&SomeInt);`, in the second case - with reference - simpler as `DoSomething(SomeInt);`

The recommended way is to use references whenever they are sufficient, and pointers only if they are necessary.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, one last thing could you please see the class example in the question?

Comment: @KKlouzal "If I pass an integer into ChangeValue, when the integer I passed in get's deleted will that mean when I try to use MyInteger from within the class it will no longer be useable?" - you cannot "delete" an integer. MyInteger just gets a new value, but is perfectly usable later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either.  Function call for first prototype would be

```
DoSomething(&SomeInt);
```

and for second prototype

```
DoSomething(SomeInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

As was already said before, you can use both. The advantage of the

```
void DoSomething(int* Integer)
{
  *Integer=0xDEADBEEF;
}
DoSomething(&myvariable);
```

pattern is that it becomes obvious from the call that myvariable is subject to change.

The advantage of the

```
void DoSomething(int& Integer)
{
  Integer=0xDEADBEEF;
}
DoSomething(myvariable);
```

pattern is that the code in DoSomething is a bit cleaner, DoSomething has a harder time to mess with memory in bad ways and that you might get better code out of it. Disadvantage is that it isn't immediately obvious from reading the call that myvariable might get changed.

Comment: If you care about `myvariable` being changed then it should already be `const`.

Comment: If you have a situation like i=0; DoSomething(i); i++; i can't be const and you do care very much whether i is changed.

Comment: So just don't do that... your code is broken. You pass `i` to functions that you don't want modifying `i` when `i` is not `const`. Very poor design.